# Windows XP powers down on boot

Tags: windows, windows-xp

This a strange one. I am working on my friend's PC with Windows XP.
As soon as it starts to boot Windows, it powers off.

If I boot in safe mode, it boots OK.

I turned off all the services and all the startup while in safe mode and it still fails.

I swapped the PS just for fun.

Ran AVG and spybot in safe mode and found nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you come up with a solution?
I am having the exact same problem, and the PC has just been running hours in Safe Mode.
I have also tried to do a System Restore with out any luck.

If it is some kind of virus/worm causing this, isn't there any tools to help you with this?

My personal guess is a faulty driver, but how can I identify this?
Is there some kind of log when Windows boots, so I can which driver was the las one loaded, when the system powers down?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whats in your startup folder? may be some kind of exe or bat file executing shutdown command.

Answer (score 0):

if you are known to virus like worms this may cause your problem there are lots of solutions:

try to **FORMAT your PC using Windows XP CD** if you have but first backup your files then before copying your files to your new **formatted** pc scan your backup files with anti virus.